# jQuery Masonry fluid layout with images

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I initiate Masonry like this:

```
container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.my-brick',
            columnWidth: function (containerWidth) {
                return (containerWidth - 80) / 4;
            }
        });
});
```

The problem is that `.my-brick` contains images that are wider then what should be calculated columnWidth. I would have expected that the script sets item's `width` CSS property to columnWidth, but it does not so the columns are as wide as pictures.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. you have to set `.my-brick` width with CSS.

A grid system is recommended.

The `columnWidth` option is there in order to set a dynamic column width if your layout has item elements that have multiple-column widths, and by column it means the absolute positions that the item is set in the DOM. It uses `columnWidth` to determine the distance between the items. If the `columnWidth` is not set then it will take the dimension of the first item